# Making top and bottom sides of bandage

Tags: modeling

How should i create top and bottom sides?
Add rolled up texture or do it with mesh?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the level of detail you wish to accomplish. If it is a minor prop for a game a texture map on a cilider will do just fine.
Otherwise I would sculpt the general form the bandage starting with a cilinder and multires. Then do a Uv unwrap and create pattern on the side by applying a displacement map and the top by sculpting using a texture. When finished  a normal map can be generated if disired